# Which window-toolkit to use for embedded linux?

Tags: android, qt, embedded, arm, embedded-linux

I am using embedded-linux for device which has Arch ARMv5 Speed 266MHZ, vfpu and 32bit bus, 32MB 133 Mhz DDR Ram. can you tell me which windowing system should I use,

1).QT for embedded linux
 2). Android.
 3). Other!!

Well, I am using microwindows for last one year and not satisfied with it as it does not have BSP (Binary Space Partitionin) in its windowing system , No shared memory support for bitmaps. I think Microwindows is just optimized for memory-size not for speed.

So,Can you please tell me what is better choice for windowing system?

Comment: Android is a Linux-based operating system, not a windowing system.

Comment: Yes, But it provides Windowing system too, And its kernel is same embedded linux. so my question is that Is it better to use android as an OS or to use QT-Embedded with My Linux Kernel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC Qt should work well with these specs. It has a configuration cabapility where you define out parts of the framework you might not want (e.g. copy/paste), and should fit in just under 3Mb on an uncompressed filesystem with the most basic of feature set. It's canvas API has a BSP index traversal algorithm, but the latest approach (recursive) is much faster. With 32Mb RAM you might find it a bit limiting but again this depends on what you are intending to do. Qt has it's own windowing system that alleviates the need to run an operating system + windowing system; QWS. For more info, check out

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6-snapshot/qt-embedded-linux.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any idea what modern OS/Windowing system you could use on a machine with those specs. What are you using it for? From the Android direction I can tell you it'll probably be underpowered for your purposes. The G1 has 6x the ram and 2x the processor and it still isn't exactly snappy. I couldn't find any specs for QTEmbedded.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [xynth](http://alperakcan.org/?open=projects&project=xynth). It's very portable.